# Использование static_cast в приведении от unsigned char к произвольному типу с содержанием union и битовых полей

Tags: c++

Есть класс PkgRecA, который содержит в себе объединение(union) Pack, которое, в свою очередь содержит структуры (struct), включающие в себя битовые поля типа unsigned char. В процессе выполнения программы происходит прием вектора значений unsigned char (std::vector) из внешнего источника данных. Поставлена задача, заключающаяся в приведении элементов принимаемого вектора  к типу PkgRecA::Pack с использованием операции static_cast. Не могу разобраться как это можно сделать. Ниже привожу код, содержащий класс и объединения:

```
namespace Protocol
```

{

```
class PackageBase
{
protected:
    std::vector<unsigned char> _data;

};

class PkgRecA : public PackageBase
{
public:
    union Pack
     {
        unsigned char base;

        struct TEL1
        {
            unsigned char     : 1;
            unsigned char MGN : 1;
            unsigned char K4P : 1;
            unsigned char NK  : 1;
            unsigned char PPP  : 1;
            unsigned char PP   : 1;
            unsigned char M_Z  : 1;
            unsigned char NKK  : 1;
        };

        struct TEL2
        {
            unsigned char     : 1;
            unsigned char KVS : 1;
            unsigned char Hm0 : 1;
            unsigned char K4  : 1;
            unsigned char KO    : 1;
            unsigned char T6M   : 1;
            unsigned char Podg  : 1;
            unsigned char Otkaz : 1;
        };

        struct TEL3
        {
            unsigned char    : 1;
            unsigned char LK : 3;
            unsigned char LT : 4;
        };
     };
public:
    PkgRecA();
};
```

Ниже привожу свой вариант использования static_cast

```
    void GUI::onComReceivedslot(std::vector<unsigned char> const& v)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        Protocol::PkgRecA::Pack &p = static_cast<Protocol::PkgRecA::Pack>(v[i]);
    }
}
```

Увы, такая запись не работает, но хотелось бы использовать что-то подобное, поэтому и прошу помощи здесь.

Comment: Добавьте сообщение об ошибке от компилятора

Comment: Не понятно, вы пытаетесь хранить в класс  PkgRecA  его же  временный экземпляр?...

Answer (score 1):

Этот union не содержит в себе никаких структур, только единственное поле `unsigned char base;`. Чтобы получить одну из структур из unsigned char инициализируйте поля этой структуры по отдельности или используйте unchecked conversion:

```
unsigned char base{};
PkgRecA::Pack::TEL1 tel;
static_assert(::std::is_standard_layout_v<decltype(tel)>);
static_assert(::std::is_standard_layout_v<decltype(base)>);
static_assert(sizeof(base) == sizeof(tel));
::std::memcpy
(
    static_cast<void *>(::std::addressof(tel))
,   static_cast<void const *>(::std::addressof(base))
,   sizeof(tel)
);
```

Ну а вообще имеет смысл отказаться от использования битовых полей, заменив их методами, тогда и преобразовывать ничего не надо будет.

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, почему это union не содержит никаких структур? Часто использую подобные конструкции, и все работает. Правда, структуры у меня часто неименованные.

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Ну это не ко мне вопрос, а к автору вопроса, отчего у него в union только одно поле. Но даже если бы в union были другие поля с типами, соответствующих структур, то обращаться к ним после инициализации поля `unsigned char base;` было бы неопределенным поведением.

Comment: Так вот я и пытаюсь понять, с чего Вы взяли, что там нет других полей, кроме base?

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов А какие поля кроме `unsigned char base;` вы там нашли? `struct TEL1` и прочие - это же не поля

Comment: три неименованных структуры типов TEL1, TEL2, TEL3 соответственно.

Comment: union DataPack

    FMezzonineClient::FArincWord pack;  //!<  Структура для передачи по каналу.
    struct
    {
        quint8       addr   : 8;        //!< Адрес (0260)
        const quint8 bit9   : 1;
        const quint8 bit10  : 1;
        quint8       year   : 8;
        quint8       month  : 5;
        quint8       day    : 6;
        quint8       mask   : 2;
        quint8       odd    : 1;
    };
};

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов Это три **именованных** структуры - имя первой `TEL1` и т.д. Полей с такими типами в  union нет.

Comment: Вот такой конструкцией пользуюсь сам, и все работает. Сорри, не знаю, как в комментах сохранить форматирование кода.

Comment: а где они тогда есть, если объявлены внутри объявления union?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95902/discussion-between---and-vtt).